# Is there any category theoretic proof for independence of Continuum Hypothesis?

Tags: reference-request, logic, category-theory, set-theory, forcing

Both of set theory and category theory could be a foundation for mathematics. Many set theoretic arguments could be translated to a category theoretic argument and vice versa.

> **Question:** Is there any category theoretic proof for independence of Continuum Hypothesis ($CH$)? What about more complicated arguments like independence of Martin's Axiom ($MA$)? Any reference for category theoretic interpretation of purely set theoretic arguments is also welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following book:

> Saunders MacLane, Ieke Moerdijk. **Sheaves in Geometry and Logic: A First Introduction to Topos Theory**, Springer New York, 1994.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the book which you introduced, addresses some of my questions.

Comment: I haven't read it, though. I just know it's there. (And that this book is a pretty standard reference for this sort of proof.)

Comment: In fact, the book proves that CH is independent. Instead of constructing new models via forcing, one constructs new topoi via presheaf categories. (That's the rough idea.)

Comment: I also wanted to recommend this book - it's beautiful!

Comment: To give you a rough idea: *Topoi* are abstractions of the category of sets in that they share some its essential properties, allowing however for non-Boolean algebras of *truth values* in general, which makes them suitable for the interpretation of intuitionistic logic. Supporting this intuition that topoi are like universes of sets, one can construct a model of $ZF$ from any *Boolean Grothendieck topos*, allowing the study of independence of CH through the construction of topoi. The relevant chapter is Ch.VI., in particular VI.2.

Answer (score 3):

There is also this paper on arXiv:  "The logic of sheaves, sheaf forcing and the independence of the Continuum Hypothesis" by J. Benavides (arXiv: 1111.5854v1 [math.LO]).